# The method putStringExtra(String, String) is undefined for the type Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to fix an issue I do not understand. I get an error "The method putStringExtra(String, String) is undefined for the type Intent" in line 4 inside my onItemClick method. What could be the reason for this?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
{
    String item=adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "You Click on:"+item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class);
    intent.putStringExtra(MyOtherActivity.TEXT_TO_DISPLAY, item);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Intent.putExtra()`. There is no method `putStringExtra()` on `Intent`. It knows what the type of the parameter is and adds the extra with its type.