# Passing ParseFile (Image) from adapter to another activity (SOLUTION)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-adapter

I have been trying to pass the image (ParseFile type) from an adapter to another activity. Since its a ParseFile I could not use normal way like, (getIntent().getIntExtra("image", 0);), to retrieve the image into the activity. If you could point me in the right direction on how to proceed that would be appreciated. Thank you.

trying to pass image from this adapter (PostsAdapter)

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Post post = posts.get(position);
    holder.bind(post);

    final ParseFile image = post.getImage();
    holder.rlPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("image", image);
            i.putExtra("description", post.getDescription());
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });`
```

Into this activity (DetailActivity)

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView ivImageD;
Post post = new Post();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    ivImageD = findViewById(R.id.ivImageD);
    ParseFile image = post.getImage();
    Glide.with(this).load(image.getUrl()).into(ivImageD);
}}
```

SOLUTION

Instead of passing Image from PostsAdapter, I passed objectId (found at Parse server) as a string and used it to retrieve Image.

in PostsAdapter

`i.putExtra("objectId", post.getObjectId());`

in DetailActivity

```
String objectId = getIntent().getStringExtra("objectId");
ParseQuery<Post> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Post.class);
    query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK); 
    query.getInBackground(objectId, new GetCallback<Post>() {
                public void done(Post item, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Item Found");
                        image = item.getImage();
                        Glide.with(DetailActivity.this).load(image.getUrl()).into(ivImageD);
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.i(TAG, "Item not Found");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is your are trying to pass the image from your viewHolder and trying to get url in DetailActivity.

Try to replace this line:

```
i.putExtra("image", image);
```

To this :

```
 i.putExtra("image", image.getUrl());
```

In DetailActivity :

```
String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(ivImageD);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. There is no such thing as putStringExtra. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399325/the-method-putstringextrastring-string-is-undefined-for-the-type-intent

Comment: @birajsilwal changed the code your code and i don't thing you need to create the post object because all you need is url in detail activity and you can pass with above solution you just need those two line.

Comment: You're right bro. Your solution worked too. But instead of i.getStringExtra("image");, it should be getIntent.getStringExtra("image");